# Magento Stop Order Till Payment Details Entered?

Tags: magento

I'am using Paypal and Barclaycard EPDQ on Magento 1.7

Is there any way to prevent Magento creating an order in the backend till payment has been received.

Hope someone can help on this,

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to hold creating orders until the payment is confirmed ?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, thanks.

Comment: No. There is no way like that, magento create the orders once the "Place Order" button has clicked in checkout page.it will only capture the invoiced details once the payment has been made successfully. all the online payment gateways are do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The quote is being generated when you click 'place order' in the checkout page [at this stage the quote is generated in Magento backend],

When you click place order it then takes me off to the Barclaycard test gateway URL.

If I don't enter any card details on this page the quote still stays in Magento backend as pending payment.

If I abandon the payment details, cart page completely the quote still stays as pending payment.Our issue its a little confusing for the client as they don't know what are true orders.

Comment: Yes all your points are correct. once the order is successfully invoiced order status is changed "Complete", orther wise it will show the "Pending Payment" Or "Processing" state. so you  will find out the succesful orders in backend.